# Unable to locate a particular button from total of 6 similar elements present on the page using selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver with java & i am unable to locate a perticular button from total of 6 similar elements present on the page.I tried using XPath with 'value' attribute as:- //input[@value = 'New PAN for Indian Citizens (Form 49A)'] but was unable to find the element.
HTML for all the 6 buttons are as follows:-

```
<input type="submit" onclick="javascript:popitup('0','',false);" style="{width:22em}"      value=" New PAN for Indian Citizens (Form 49A) " name="submit">

<input type="submit" onclick="javascript:popitup('5','',false);" style="{width:22em}"     value=" New PAN for Foreign Citizens (Form 49AA) " name="submit">

<input type="submit" onclick="javascript:popitup('1','',false);" style="{width:22em}"     value="Changes or Correction in PAN details" name="submit">

<input type="submit" onclick="javascript:popitup('1','',false);" style="{width:22em}"     value=" Reprint of PAN card " name="submit">

<input type="submit" onclick="javascript:popitup('2','',false);" style="{width:22em}"     value=" Transaction Status Enquiry " name="submit">

<input type="submit" onclick="javascript:popitup('3','',false);" style="{width:22em}"     value=" Status Track for PAN application " name="submit">
```

Please help me folks. . . thanks in advance

Comment: //input[@value = 'New PAN for --- new is not preceding any space, but in code, its like " New -- can you check once, if this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should mention attribute values in the same way as mentioned in HTML,so even the space matters...

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value=' New PAN for Indian Citizens (Form 49A) ']"));
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=' New PAN for Indian Citizens (Form 49A) ']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try a partial match:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(value, '(Form 49A)')]"));
```

Comment: Thanks lllya. . it was useful